# Thread Safety of Matrix<> Vector<>in MathNet

Tags: c#, math.net

I’ve searched this site and the Math.Net 2 site, but I’ve been unable to find any definitive information about thread safety.

Are MathNet objects thread safe? For example, if I create an object(s)
`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix`
or
`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`
can use MathNet functions, e.g. `Add()`, `At()`, etc from multiple threads in my application? How about something like `MathNet.Numerics.Control.UseMultiThreading()` ?

To be clear, I’m not asking about multi-threading within MathNet functions, but rather the thread safety of the objects themselves using multiple threads created within my application.

Thanks

Comment: I would have thought a math library be stateless anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source for the backing storages](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/tree/master/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Storage) (`DenseVectorStorage`, `SparseVectorStorage`, and the Matrix-related storages), they use simple arrays to store the indices & data, with no thread safety checks.

e.g. `SparseVectorStorage.At()` contains a simple `return itemIndex >= 0 ? Values[itemIndex] : Zero;`

The lack of thread safety is understandable, as the library aims to be fast, and the user is free to slow it down and add thread safety themselves if needed.

As for your question about `Control.UseMultiThreading()` (and its lack of documentation), that seems to be mostly used to speed up calculations, especially since the nature of linear algebra calculations being highly parallelisable, without having to modify existing structures.

Comment: So since there is a single storage object per thread, than we *CAN* assume thread safety. Also, it looks like the Control object follows the Singleton Pattern, so that would greatly limit fine grain configuration across different threads.

Comment: Thread-safety means that if you have *multiple threads* operating on *a single object*, they shall not interfere with each other. The Vector & Matrix storages are most certainly not thread-safe. Take the `SparseVectorStorage` as an example. It involves a lot of array resizing upon setting a value. If you have 100 threads operating on a single vector, simultaneously setting a value at [0..99], I can guarantee you won't end up with a 100-length vector because of the race condition of each thread trying to resize the array at the same time.